# Why is Beautiful Soup Returning duplicate results?

Tags: python, html, selenium, web, beautifulsoup

I am creating a project that scrapes indeeds website and it was working fine but when I ran it today, all of a sudden without having made any changes, instead of returning the entire page of results, it no only displays the first result in duplicates. May someone help me correct this

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pandas as pd
import requests


html_text = requests.get('https://www.ign.com/').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')
jobs = soup.find('section',class_='right')
#print(html_text)


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/Miscellaneous/PycharmProjects/RecursivePractice/chromedriver')
url= "https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=developer&l=Westbury%2C%20NY&vjk=0b0cbe29e5f86422"
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(5)
content = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8').strip()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")
officials = soup.findAll("a",{"class":"tapItem"}

for official in officials:
  jobTitle = soup.find('h2',{'class': 'jobTitle'}).text
  companyName = soup.find('div',{'class': 'comapny_location'})
  location = soup.find('div',{'class': 'companyLocation'}).text
  salary = soup.find('div',{'class': 'salary-snippet'})
  actualSalary = salary.find('span').text
  summary = soup.find('div',{'class': 'job-snippet'}).text

print('Title: ' + str(jobTitle) + '\nCompany Name: ' + str(companyName) + '\nLocation: ' + str(location)
      + '\nSalary: ' + str(actualSalary) + "\nSummary: " + str(summary))
#print(str(official))
print(' ')


driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pandas as pd
import requests


html_text = requests.get('https://www.ign.com/').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')
jobs = soup.find('section',class_='right')


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/Miscellaneous/PycharmProjects/RecursivePractice/chromedriver')
url= "https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=developer&l=Westbury%2C%20NY&vjk=0b0cbe29e5f86422"
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(5)
content = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8').strip()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")
officials = soup.findAll("a",{"class":"tapItem"})

for i in range(len(officials)):
    jobTitle = soup.findAll('h2',{'class': 'jobTitle'})[i].text

    companyName = soup.findAll('div',{'class': 'comapny_location'})[i].text if len(soup.findAll('div',{'class': 'comapny_location'})) > i else "NULL"
    location = soup.findAll('div',{'class': 'companyLocation'})[i].text if len(soup.findAll('div',{'class': 'companyLocation'})) > i else "NULL"
    salary = soup.findAll('div',{'class': 'salary-snippet'})[i].text if len(soup.findAll('div',{'class': 'salary-snippet'})) > i else "NULL"
    actualSalary = salary.find('span')
    summary = soup.findAll('div',{'class': 'job-snippet'})[i].text if len(soup.findAll('div',{'class': 'job-snippet'})) > i else "NULL"

    print('Title: ' + str(jobTitle) + '\nCompany Name: ' + str(companyName) + '\nLocation: ' + str(location)
        + '\nSalary: ' + str(actualSalary) + "\nSummary: " + str(summary))
    print(' ')

driver.quit()
```

Comment: It worked for the most part, thank you so much! may you explain why you added the additional "if statements". I only understand your answer up until the "[i].text" in the middle of each line. and still have no idea why it was returning duplicatesin the first place. Please and thank you :)

Comment: Also why didnt you have to add that extra stuff to to "jobTitle" and why does "actualSalary" not work now. Beautiful soup has been so frustrating lately lol

Comment: Answering your first Question: The additional if expressions prevents the program from running into `index out of range` error. Now it first checks if there are enough elements in the list then try to retrieve and return "NULL" otherwise. Earlier in your code, the print statements were out of your loop. That's why it was returning the last value retrieved.
Answering your second Question: `actualSalary` don't have `[i]` indexing

Comment: I actually indented the print statement incorrectly when placing it on SO, it is within the loop for my actual program. My biggest problem is though that the way I originally did it worked perfectly fine. I feel like the duplicate results problem literally came out of no where without me having changed anything :(